# Imports and using Tilt.js in Angular 2 project generate with angular-cli

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an **Angular2** project generated with **angular-cli**. I am trying to use this javascript library: ***https://micku7zu.github.io/vanilla-tilt.js/***
. As it stands, I save the minified js file in my assets folder. The code below is just there for me to be thorough. Added a script pointing to that file in my angular-cli.json file:

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "name": "HowDoICorrectlyUseExtraJSFiles"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        "assets/js/vanilla-tilt.min.js" //ADDED JS FILE HERE (paths are correct and are loaded in the browser)
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "src/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "e2e/**/*.ts",
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

In addition, I added a script to my index.html file, although I would like to avoid this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kompario</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/vanilla-tilt.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "kompario",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

So my question is: **How do I correctly import a JS library like tilt.js into my recently generated angular-cli project? More specifically, how do I use it's directives in my templates and controllers?**

Comment: I'm confused. This library doesn't appear to be an Angular library therefore there are no directives to be accessed from it. You would need to write your own wrapper around the library that would expose it through components/directives.

Comment: @JesseCarter well then you have pointed out my confusion as well. I have no idea how to what what you just mentioned.